# Printing every entry in a list on its own individual line in Python

Tags: python, list, printing

Say I have an array thusly:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to have it be printed like so:

```
1
2
3
4
```

but I don't want to go:

```
print(a[0])
print(a[1])
print(a[2])
print(a[3])
```

I want it to automatically print each entry, but dynamically enough so that it stops when there is nothing more, but keeps going if there is, if that makes any sense. I'm not very good at words when it comes to programming, but I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

Join the list together with linefeeds:

```
print '\n'.join(a)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a loop:

```
for x in a:
    print x
```

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory Python3 answer:

```
[print(k) for k in a]
```

`print` is a function in Python3.

Comment: Please don't do this! Think about what this does in memory: constructs a len(a) list of 'None's, just to throw it away.

Sure, that's fine for a 4-element array, but in the general case it's a terrible idea, and we shouldn't promote this type of waste.

Comment: @llimllib : Although your argument is entirely right, we're assuming here OP is not printing to the screen thousands of elements. The memory argument may be valid in some rare cases, but let's not try to optimize what doesn't have to be optimized.

Comment: My point is, we shouldn't recommend this style to anyone, especially impressionable newbies. It's bad form.

Comment: @llimllib: I understood your point, and while correct, I don't think it applies here. We don't know any constraints, we don't know what the typical list to be printed will be, etc. Will my code waste some bytes of memory? Yes. Will it have any impact? Absolutely not, in almost every case.
Let me therefore disagree with you, even if it is not a general solution, it answers OP's problem with little to no consequences in general.